# What are some other neat uses for a Linux Server?

Tags: linux

I bought a hosted VPS with Linux. Specifically for a request tracker installation, that currently blows away our current "custom" helpdesk software that only works right on IE 6.0. but my bosses aren't having any of it. So I'm left with a VPS paid for a year. What are some other neat or cool uses I can do with it?

thanks in advance. my sincere apologies if this is a "bad" question for this forum.

Comment: Community Wiki...

Answer (score 1):

I hear that Web sites are pretty cool to run and use, there's always Apache.

Fun things but could be applied to work as well..

- IRC Server

  - Eggdrop bot
  - BNC
- MUD
- Telnet BBS
- Jabber server

(Well, the MUD or BBS probably wouldn't be applicable to business needs really.)

Practical things..

- External monitoring

  - Availability
  - Performance
- Server with no access restrictions for testing
- Server for testing your production application externally
- Running services that are unable to comply to your internal security policy but have business justification.